# Call rest service that returns JSON in mule esb?

Tags: json, rest, mule, raml

How to call a rest service that returns JSON in a APIKit based message flow. I want to prepare the request for Rest service and want to extract the JSON message in a message flow.

Can any one help me to do this?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? What errors are you getting, if any? Do you have any code that we can look at?

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way to invoke/consume REST services in mule is the use of [HTTP Request](https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/HTTP+Request+Connector)

Do let us know if there is a specific you are facing

> The request connector is especially handy when consuming a RESTful API
>   that is described in a RAML file. If you reference the API's RAML file
>   in the connector's configuration, it will proactively offer you the
>   set of available resources and operations contained in the RAML file,
>   as well as enforce the policies described in the file. It will also
>   expose the API metadata to Studio, which can then be used by other
>   elements such as DataWeave to autocomplete fields and make
>   configuration much easier

Answer (score -1):

Use Rest URI path to invoke the Service and you can also get json response as output based on the type of service you invoke